# Session state server saying extended class no serializable

Tags: asp.net, serialization, session-state

I am storing an object in session state (using local session state server), class def is:

```
 [Serializable]
 public class ExtendedOAuth2Parameters : OAuth2Parameters
```

but the service is still reporting:

```
Unable to serialize the session state. In 'StateServer' and 'SQLServer' mode, ASP.NET will serialize the session state objects, and as a result non-serializable objects or MarshalByRef objects are not permitted.

[SerializationException: Type 'Google.GData.Client.OAuth2Parameters' in Assembly 'Google.GData.Client, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=04a59ca9b0273830' is not marked as serializable.]
```

How to get around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the error message, it looks like the base class (`Google.GData.Client.OAuth2Parameters`) is not serializable, so even though you have marked your class with the `Serializable` attribute, the complete class hierarchy is not.

You would either need to use a bass class that is itself serializable, or if you have access to the code (probably don't?), make the `Google.GData.Client.OAuth2Parameters` class serializable.

Keep in mind that 'serializability' is dependent on the complete type tree for any given class - i.e. all base classes and member classes also need to be serializable for the enclosing class to be truly serializable.

Comment: yes these were my suspicions, i have since been refactoring my code to persist something else to session and hydrate it to the 3rd party class on retrieval